# В регулярных выражениях js не находит совпаднение

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Написал такой простенький код:

```
var text = " вирус ";
text.match(/^вирус$/);
```

А совпадении нет. Если убрать пробелы в переменной text, то находит.

Мне нужно чтобы данное слово можно было найти где угодно в тексте. Если убрать знаки начала и конца, то он находит, в том числе и такие варианты: "вирусам","вирусов" и т.д., а мне нужно точное совпадение, а именно "вирус". Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Так это знаки начала и конца строки, а не слова. Для слов есть \b, но не уверен что это работает для русских букв

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ужасающе выглядит, но зато работает

```js
var v = `...  вирус,  вирусы, вирусов, вирус антивирус снова вирус  ...`
console.log(v.match(/(^|(?<=[^a-яё]))вирус((?=[^a-яё])|$)/igm))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот такой вариант. С учетом того, что слово записано на русском, получается несколько монстровидно

```
(^|[\s.,:;!?])(вирус)([\s.,:;!?]|$)

[\s.,:;!?] это граница слова.
```

Слово начинается либо с начала строки, либо с символа границы и заканчивается либо символом границы либо концом строки.

Можно использовать более простую форму

```
\b(вирус)\b
```

но она может не работать для русского языка (зависит от реализации regexp).

для латиницы работает

```
\b(virus)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

В JS с поддержкой ECMAScript 2018+ граница слова может выглядеть так:

```js
const v = `...  вирус,  вирусы, вирусов, вирус антивирус снова вирус  ...`
console.log(v.match(/(?<![\p{L}\p{N}_])вирус(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])/ug))
```

Из `(?<![\p{L}\p{N}_])вирус(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])/ug` можно удалить знаки подчёркивания, если нужно найти `вирус` в `_вирус_`.

Модификатор `u` необходим для правильной обработки классов Юникода `\p{...}`.

`(?<![\p{L}\p{N}_])` - отрицающий блок просмотра назад, находит позицию в строке, сразу перед которой не должно быть любой буквы, цифры или `_`.

`(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])` - отрицающий блок просмотра вперёд, находит позицию в строке, сразу *после* которой не должно быть любой буквы, цифры или `_`.